# How do I run Docker Swarm's integration tests?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, integration-testing, docker-swarm

I've followed the instructions at https://github.com/docker/swarm/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md to run Swarm's integration tests, but they do not work. The command `./test/integration/run.sh` gives unusual error messages. (See http://pastebin.com/hynTXkNb for the full output).

The message about swappiness is the first thing that looks wrong. My kernel *does* support it - I tested it. /proc/sys/vm/swappiness is readable and writable, and configurable through sysctl.conf .

The next line that looks wrong is the chmod. It tries to access a file in /usr/local/bin - which is wrong because Docker is installed to /usr/bin , and because that file wouldn't be writable by anyone but root anyway.

I know the daemon is running, and working correctly. For example:

```
user@box:~$ docker run debian /bin/echo 'hello world asdf'
WARNING: Your kernel does not support memory swappiness capabilities, memory swappiness discarded.
hello world asdf
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue, and get the integration tests running?

If not, does anyone at least know where to dig into the code in Docker to find out what is failing?